# Can't figure out how to do imports correctly

Tags: rust, import

I have a Rust project with the following structure:

```
|_src
   |
   |_main.rs
   |_bin
      |_rotor.rs
      |_plugboard.rs
      |_reflector.rs
      |_enigma.rs
      |_mod.rs
```

and as you may have guessed, it's an implementation of Enigma coding machine. The `main.rs` handles the generall running of the program, specifically, handles all the comman line arguments.

Then `enigma.rs` contains the struct that does all the encoding and decoding and it contains references to `rotor.rs`, `plugboard.rs` and `reflector.rs`.

While I was developing all the internals inside `bin` all normal references would work. For example, in `enigma.rs` on top of file I would have:

```
use reflector::Reflector;
use rotor::Rotor;
use plugboard::Plugboard;
```

and all worked fine.

When I started working on `main.rs` and needed to import structs from `enigma.rs` I was getting import errors so I did what some SO answers recommended - on top of `main.rs` I have:

```
mod bin;
use bin::enigma::*;
```

and inside `bin` I have a `mod.rs` with the following:

```
pub mod enigma;
pub mod rotor;
pub mod plugboard;
pub mod reflector;
```

But now all the imports in `enigma.rs` are showing errors:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `reflector`
 --> src/bin/enigma.rs:4:5
  |
4 | use reflector::Reflector;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^ help: a similar path exists: `crate::reflector`
  |
  = note: `use` statements changed in Rust 2018; read more at <https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html>
```

I've tried going down the link included and tried the examples there but nothing seems to work. I'm so confused.

I also tried changing imports inside `enigma.rs` to use the modules name:

```
use bin::reflector::Reflector;
use bin::rotor::Rotor;
use bin::plugboard::Plugboard;
```

But I get told that crate or module `bin` is undeclared. And if I try and declare it (which I know won't work but I'm grasping at straws) then I get:

```
error[E0583]: file not found for module `bin`
 --> src/bin/enigma.rs:4:1
  |
4 | mod bin;
  | ^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: to create the module `bin`, create file "src/bin/enigma/bin.rs" or "src/bin/enigma/bin/mod.rs"
```

I swear to god, no matter what language I use, imports are always the most confusing part.

Comment: @cafce25, I tried that and I get the message that "could not find reflector in crate root'

Comment: I'm pretty sure `src/bin` is special folder for Cargo, and every file in it is treated as an additional binary crate.

Comment: @IvanC, I moved modules in a different folder but still imports don't work.

Comment: @IvanC, actually the combination of your advice and the one from `cafce25` solved the issue. I moved all submodules into `modules/` directory and then imported in `enigma.rs` using `super::plugboard::Plugboard;` etc. This seems to work fine